# rtorrent copy after download

Tags: cp, rtorrent

so I`m trying to do the following:

When rtorrent finishes download, it should copy files from download dir to another dir called uploads, so the file would be in Downloads dir AND in Uploads dir.

Before this I was using mv function to move file from Downloads to Uploads an here is a working example so you could understand rtorrents syntax:

```
system.method.set_key = event.download.finished,move_complete,"execute=mv,-u,$d.get_base_path=,~/uploads/"
```

This is working preview it executes "mv -u /home/downloads/folder1/ ~/uploads/, so basically it moves the torrent with the same name just to another dir.

The thing I do NOT get it how can I copy files (folders and files, depending on what Im downloading) with the same name, lets say:

/home/dl/harry potter/ ------> /home/ul/harry potter/

and next one could be

/home/dl/ubuntu.iso ------> /home/ul/ubuntu.iso

Answer (score 2):

Using the 'cp' command, e.g. "execute=cp,$d.get_base_path=,/home/ul/"

Though I don't know if '$d.get_base_path=' will be properly escaped in either case.

edit: Jeremy is right, you should add '-R' for recursive.
You should also add '-l' if dl/ and ul/ are on the same file-system, so that they are hard-linked.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the recursive flag ('-R') so that directories are properly copied: `execute=cp,-R,$d.get_base_path=,/home/ul/`

Comment: Hey Jeremy, thanks for the tip. Note that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion site. I think your comment is better posted as comment to somebody else's answer. Or you could flesh it out into a complete answer (and earn some reputation points).